# Replace all string to @lang() in laravel blade file

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hello Artisan in my laravel blade file i have my string as e.g
`{{__('test string')}}` and some as `Test string` without bracket,
my question is there any way i can use vscode to update all string to into `@lang('test string')` in all blade file?

i have tried repacing the string manually in all file but too many of them

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can press the Regex replace button.

Then use a string like this:

```
/{{\s*__\('(.+?)'\)\s*}}/gm
```

Or this for double quotes:

```
/{{\s*__\("(.+?)"\)\s*}}/gm
```

You can see what that matches here:

https://regex101.com/r/tH7JjU/1

Then I believe you can use `$1` or similar in the replacement. If you Google regex search replace vscode you should get there.

**Update**

In vscode the `/` and `/gm` are managed by the editor so you can remove those from the start and the end. The `{` and `}` need to be escaped using a `\`.

```
\{\{\s*__\('(.+?)'\)\s*\}\}
```

Then replace

```
@lang('$1')
```

[image]

Note the Regex button `.*` next to the search is highlighted